# How to put IntelliJ/Pycharm settings under version control?

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, jar, settings, pycharm

I'm a frequent user of PyCharm and a number of the other JetBrains IDEs. I try to keep my settings synchronized across the different IDEs, but I'm now considering moving to IntelliJ IDEA and am finding it extremely difficult to figure out what I've changed and what the differences are among my different settings files.

How can I put my PyCharm settings files under version control so that I can track my changes and also quickly revert back to old versions so I can try out new settings changes without fear?

(I don't mind exporting to a specific repo each time, but it seems that the settings always export as JAR files, which don't lend themselves to VCS.)

Comment: The global settings should be in a bunch of XML files under `$HOME/.IntellijIdea15/config` (this is platform dependend though, see [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/directories-used-by-intellij-idea-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) for more details). Project specific settings are in `.idea/` in the project directory. So I would personally try to put first mentioned directory under VC, change few settings and observe what happens (haven't tried it personally)

Answer (score 3):

I am using the [Settings Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7566) plugin to syncronize settings between PyCharm and PhpStorm and it is working very well. It is actually designed with version control and team sharing in mind, see [project repo on github](https://github.com/develar/settings-repository) and have built in support for conflict resolution, merge and overwriting remote or local.

It does also support file system and, from what I can tell, what then is stored is the mirror version of the git repository.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm (at least the Linux 4.X and 5.0 Pro versions) places its config files in a `.idea` dir under the project dir:

```
$ find .idea/
.idea/
.idea/libraries
.idea/libraries/Google_App_Engine_SDK.xml
.idea/libraries/Generated_files.xml
.idea/apartsw.iml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/runConfigurations
.idea/runConfigurations/apartsw.xml
.idea/encodings.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/inspectionProfiles
.idea/inspectionProfiles/MyProject.xml
.idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml
.idea/watcherTasks.xml
.idea/webResources.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/scopes
.idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/dictionaries/username.xml
```

I added the entire dir with the exception of `.idea/workspace.xml` into the project's `git` repo, following JetBrains' [PyCharm-specific](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/managing-projects-under-version-control.html) and/or [generic `.idea`-based Tools](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827587-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems) recommendations.