# Run/Debug configurations are lost in Pycharm 2016.3 after upgrade

Tags: pycharm

I've upgraded from Pycharm 2016.2.3, I selected import existing configuration but new version of Pycharm lost all of my Run/Debug configurations.

I checked the system/config folder and found the same archives. Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: Also check the project's `.idea` dir, not only your personal settings. If you put them under version control you may be able to recover them. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34013191/4495081

Comment: I had some backups, so I recovered. But I had to switch to the previous version because of this. Thanks.

Comment: OK, make copies then try the upgrade again. Keep an eye on the automatic changes to the files that the newer version does. Maybe it was just a glitch, or maybe the configs changed in a non-backwards-compatible way. In the worst case you'll have to create new configs but at least  you can copy-paste values from the old config file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PyCharm 2017.3 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) (the same text is in previous versions, too -  see e.g. [PyCharm 2016.2 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)):

> Important note for multi-project usage
>
> If a project has been created in an earlier version of PyCharm, its run/debug configurations can be lost, when such a project is added to another project, already opened in the same window.
>
> To avoid the loss of run/debug configurations, it is recommended to open such a project once in the latest version, and only after being added to another project.

I know, it would be better for you to read it *in advance*; now it only *explains a possible reason*.

Comment: my friend. The question was added long time before 2017.3 version was created. And I read it.